# Passing class functions to PySpark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a class named some_class() in a Python file here:

```
/some-folder/app/bin/file.py
```

I am importing it to my code here:

```
/some-folder2/app/code/file2.py
```

By

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/some-folder/app/bin')
from file import some_class

clss = some_class()
```

I want to use this class's function named some_function in map of spark

```
sc.parallelize(some_data_iterator).map(lambda x: clss.some_function(x))
```

This is giving me an error :

```
No module named file
```

While class.some_function when I am calling it outside map function of pyspark i.e. normally but not in pySpark's RDD. I think this has something to do with pyspark. I have no idea where am I going wrong in this.

I tried broadcasting this class and still didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Python dependencies have to be either present on the search path of the worker nodes or distributed manually using `SparkContext.addPyFile` method so something like this should do the trick:

```
sc.addPyFile("/some-folder/app/bin/file.py")
```

It will copy the file to all the workers and place in the working directory.

On a side note please don't use `file` as module name, even if it is only an example. Shadowing built-in functions in Python is not a very good idea.

Comment: Is there a way to add a folder to the path instead of one single file

Comment: addPyFile can take a `zip` file.  You can zip your entire source tree, then add it with addPyFile.