# using python class methods on RDD

Tags: python, class, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

My question may sound somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505426/how-to-process-rdds-using-a-python-class) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569633/passing-class-functions-to-pyspark-rdd) but trying the solutions of these also didn't helped me out.
I have a class tokenizer defined as-

```
class Tokenizer:
    def __init__(self, preserve_case=False):
        self.preserve_case = preserve_case

    def tokenize(self, s):
        """
        Argument: s -- any string or unicode object
        Value: a tokenize list of strings; conatenating this list returns the original string if preserve_case=False
        """        
        # Try to ensure unicode:
        try:
            s = str(s)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            s = s.encode('string_escape')
            s = str(s)
        # Fix HTML character entitites:
        s = self.__html2unicode(s)
        # Tokenize:
        words = word_re.findall(s)
        # Possible alter the case, but avoid changing emoticons like :D into :d:
        if not self.preserve_case:            
            words = map((lambda x : x if emoticon_re.search(x) else x.lower()), words)
        return words
tok=Tokenizer(preserve_case=False)
```

I have a (key,value) RDD of (user_id, tweets). I want to use the the tweets of the RDD on the function tokenize of class tokenizer. What I did was-

```
rdd.foreach(lambda x:tok.tokenize(x[1])).take(5)
```

and got the error-

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'take'

I also tried-

```
rdd1.map(lambda x:tok.tokenize(x[1])).take(5)
```

and got the error-

> > Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)  in ()
> >     ----> 1 rdd1.map(lambda x:tok.tokenize(x[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505426/how-to-process-rdds-using-a-python-class))).take(5)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py in take(self,
>   num)    1358     1359             p = range(partsScanned,
>   min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
>   -> 1360             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)    1361     1362             items += res
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in
>   runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)    1067
>
> ## SparkContext#runJob.    1068         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
>
> -> 1069         sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)    1070         return
>   list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
>   1071
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in
>   **call**(self, *args)    1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)    1256         return_value
>   = get_return_value(
>   -> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)    1258     1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in
>   get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       329             else:
>       330                 raise Py4JError(
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 39.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.0 in stage 39.0 (TID 101, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/home/kriti/Downloads/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 377, in main
>       process()   File "/home/kriti/Downloads/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 372, in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)   File
>   "/home/kriti/Downloads/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 397, in dump_stream
>       bytes = self.serializer.dumps(vs)   File "/home/kriti/Downloads/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 576, in dumps
>       return pickle.dumps(obj, protocol) AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Tokenizer.tokenize..'
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)  at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
>     at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:153)    at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/home/kriti/Downloads/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 377, in main
>       process()   File "/home/kriti/Downloads/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 372, in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)   File
>   "/home/kriti/Downloads/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 397, in dump_stream
>       bytes = self.serializer.dumps(vs)   File "/home/kriti/Downloads/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 576, in dumps
>       return pickle.dumps(obj, protocol) AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Tokenizer.tokenize..'
>
> at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRunner.scala:571)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)  at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
>     at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more

Any help would be grateful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `rdd.foreach(lambda x:tok.tokenize(x[1])).take(5)`

Here you are trying to access the results from [rdd.foreach()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html#foreach) which is null.

> `rdd1.map(lambda x:tok.tokenize(x[1])).take(5)`

Here you are using a custom object with lambda this throws the next exception:

> AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Tokenizer.tokenize..'

which practically it means that pyspark failes to serialize the `Tokenizer.tokenize` method. One possible solution is to call `tok.tokenize(x[1])` from a function and then pass a reference to that function in map as shown below:

```py
def tokenize(x):
  return tok.tokenize(x[0])

rdd1.map(tokenize).take(5)
```

Also in your code you have one more issue. Class Tokenizer is trying to access the undeclared `self.__html2unicode(s)` method. This will cause the following error:

```py
AttributeError: 'Tokenizer' object has no attribute '_Tokenizer__html2unicode'
```

Related topics

[PySpark: PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle CompiledFFI objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789355/pyspark-picklingerror-could-not-serialize-object-typeerror-cant-pickle-comp)

https://github.com/yahoo/TensorFlowOnSpark/issues/198